# Save Arraybuffer from IndexedDB entry

Tags: html, indexeddb

It is possible to store blobs and arraybuffers in indexedDB (as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833387/saving-arraybuffer-in-indexeddb)). My problem is, that I am storing pdf files in the storage and want to "download" them when the user clicks on a specific link. Is it possible to "download" files from the local indexDB database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using native JavaScript or the IndexedDB API, but check out FileWriter and BlobBuilder parts of the upcoming [Filesystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

Answer (score 1):

This questions isn't really IndexedDB related, but rather simply "How do I get the user to save a Blob object". A Blob works the same way, no matter if you've loaded it from IndexedDB or if you got it from somewhere else.

Using a FileSaver would be the best solution, had it been consistently implemented, but it's not.

What should work is to do something like this:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob); // This is the magic!
iframe.src = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to save Blobs in indexedDb

```
objectStore.put({ id: idValue, blobdata: data })
```