# base64 image, compression and saving to local DB

Tags: javascript, image, base64, gzip, offline

So for offline application that have dynamic content and images, it is necessary to save images in local DB like indexedDB or something else.

But because browsers always have different size allowed for local DB, it is important to have images compressed somehow.

So idea is to get image.png from server and on client side with javascript convert it to base64. So now we have string and we can store it to DB, but that string is evan bigger than original jpeg/png and it would be good somehow to zip it before.

Does someone know how to gzip base64 image with javascript?

thnx,

Comment: Why do you need to base64 encode it? As for compression, google came up with http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html. Also, a PNG image will be very difficult to compress any further as it is already compressed.

Comment: I need to save image to indexedDB and to store it I convert it from jpg/png  to base64 but this format is evan bigger than jpeg/png. Need somehow to make it less size

Comment: So don't convert it to base64. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833387/saving-arraybuffer-in-indexeddb.

Answer (score 1):

I need some days ago. After my search I'm using this algorithm: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/LZW_compression

I have about 1:5 compress tax, for my base64 string.

Answer (score 0):

If you can store binary data in your database, then just reverse the Base 64 coding.  Or if you're doing it, don't encode it in Base 64 in the first place.  The .png file is already compressed, so compressing it again won't help.