# How to store ArrayBuffers in a browser web-extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, firefox-addon-webextensions

Sometimes browser extensions need to persist some data, for which MDN suggests to use the `browser.storage.<StorageArea>` interface (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea)). It says however:

> Values may be primitive types (such as numbers, booleans, and strings)
>   or Array types.
>
> It's generally not possible to store other types, such as Function,
>   Date, RegExp, Set, Map, ArrayBuffer and so on. Some of these
>   unsupported types will restore as an empty object, and some cause
>   set() to throw an error. The exact behavior here is browser-specific.

(see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/set )

Since the data I attempt to store are ArrayBuffers that contain binary data, I wonder if there is a way to store such binary data, **other than** to convert it back-and-forth to an intermediate String representation?

With [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8833387/1711186), which asks also about how to persist/store `ArrayBuffers` using `IndexedDB`, I am tempted to believe that it might be possible to use hence `IndexedDB` interface, but am unsure:

1. Its currently highest [rated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11059279/1711186) does imho says that `ArrayBuffers` should be working, because of their structured clone situation. But even this answer is challanged by the unclear/lacking specification/standard/reference.
2. MDN hints on using `browser.storage.local` over other data persisting APIs like for instance `localStorage`, since the later is more prone to its data being deleted.

> Although this API *[browser.storage.local]( is similar to Window.localStorage it is recommended
>   that you don't use Window.localStorage in extension code. Firefox will
>   clear data stored by extensions using the localStorage API in various
>   scenarios where users clear their browsing history and data for
>   privacy reasons, while data saved using the storage.local API will be
>   correctly persisted in these scenarios.

Which makes me question the reliability of `IndexedDB` as well.

However I cannot, but think it would be quite some missing thing, if web extensions would lack a way to store binary data. Therefore the question:

** How are web extensions supposed to store binary data such as ArrayBuffers ?**

**UPDATE**

besides the quoted warning from MDN it seems possible to store ArrayBuffers,
without any problem like this:

```
var u8array = new Uint8Array(100);
for(var i=0;i<u8array.length;i++)u8array[i]=i;
var storedPromise = 
   browser.storage.local.set({"u8arraybuffer":u8array.buffer});
storedPromise.then(()=>{
   browser.storage.local.get("u8arraybuffer").then((result)=>{
       var u8arrayFromStorage = new Uint8Array(result.u8arraybuffer);
       console.log("u8arrayFromStorage",u8arrayFromStorage);
       // prints:
       // u8arrayFromStorage 
       // Uint8Array(100) [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, … ]
   });      
});
```

which seems to suggest there is indeed not any problem (?anymore) to store
ArrayBuffer within `browser.storage.local` API. 
Maybe an answer could assist in confirming that despite the MDN warnings it is completely possible/permissible to store `ArrayBuffer`s via `browser.storage.<StorageArea>`

Comment: IndexedDB is 100% capable of storing ArrayBuffer as per the specification, both as a value and as a key.

Comment: @wOxxOm The answer I have refered to seemed however to struggle as regards to provide a specification that supports "ArrayBuffer" can be stored in IndexedDB. Am I reading the answer wrong? More importantly however, as I mentioned in the question, I do not want to use `IndexedDB` API (even if it is capable of ArrayBuffer's as values/keys) it it comes at the costs of being at higher risk than `browser.storage` API, when it comes to data being removed by the browser (i.e. once caches/browsing data is cleared).

Comment: 1) Just ignore that ancient answer, read the spec, it's easy. 2) As for the risk of clearing, well, I don't think it should be a factor, instead you may want to educate your users, e.g. show a warning or suggest backing up data. 3) As for your code, I suspect it just converts the data to a standard array under the hood so you should check the storage file in the browser profile directory to see what's being actually stored.